# Why are my lists getting bigger when I use .insert() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a game of hangman for homework and I've been struggling to figure out why the list messes up after I the letters are added into the correct spaces.

For my hangman game, I have two lists, one that has the word which needs to be guessed and another which has what the player has guessed. I use a for loop to correctly identify where the letters are in the 'word to be guessed' list and place them into the 'guessed' list.

When I do this, and print the 'guessed' list afterwards, the list gets messed up.

I'm not looking for a massive improvement to my code, as I am just trying to learn the basics (it is homework), I'm just trying to fix this specific error. I've also never used lists until this homework so I'm still learning how to use them haha.

Thank you!

```
finished = False
selected_word = input("Can player one input a word?")
selected_word_list = list(selected_word)
length_of_word = len(selected_word_list)


guessed_word = []
for x in range(0, length_of_word):
    guessed_word.append('_')

while finished == False:
    place_of_x = -1
    guess = input("Please enter a letter: ")
    if guess in selected_word_list:
        print("Well done you have found a letter")
        for x in selected_word_list:
            place_of_x = place_of_x + 1
            if x == guess:
                guessed_word.insert(place_of_x,guess)      
        print(guessed_word)
```

I expect the list to still be the same length.
E.g. if I input 'banana' and guess 'a', the output is:

```
['_', 'a', '_', 'a', '_', 'a', '_', '_', '_']
```

when I want it to be:

```
['_', 'a', '_', 'a', '_', 'a']
```

Comment: FYI, you can replace the first loop with `guessed_word = ['_'] * length_of_word`

Comment: Thank you! That's much easier :)

Comment: You can also use `for place_of_x, x in enumerate(selected_word_list):`

Answer (score 6):

You have a misunderstanding of what `insert` does. `insert` inserts an additional new element into the list, in front of the position given in the first argument.

What you appear to want to do is *replace* an item. This can be done by simple indexing:

```
guessed_word[place_of_x] = guess
```

Answer (score 0):

A few improvement suggestions:

- consider converting the input to lower/upper case, so that the letters get matched correctly.
- Maybe check that the user enters a single letter when guessing
- you can use `for i, elem in enumerate(selected_word_list):` instead of increasing `place_of_x` manually

Here is a possible improved version:

```
def func():
    # strip whitespaces from the beginning/end, make all lowercase
    selected_word_list = list(input("Input a word: ").strip().lower())

    length_of_word = len(selected_word_list)
    guessed_word = ['_', ] * length_of_word

    while True:
        print(guessed_word)

        # strip whitespaces from the beginning/end, make lowercase
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").strip().lower()

        if guess in selected_word_list:
            print("Well done you have found a letter")

            for i, elem in enumerate(selected_word_list):
                if elem == guess:
                    guessed_word[i] = guess

        print(guessed_word)

        if '_' not in guessed_word:
            print("Finished")
            print(guessed_word)

            # exit the function, which exists the loop as well
            return
```